# Unable to get disabled AD accounts in People picker

Tags: people-picker

I want to access an account which is disabled in Active Directory using people picker.I have set the stsadm property  peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter and  peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery using below script to set people picker to show only user which are disabled in AD but not working.

stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomquery -pv "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -url

stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -url

See below link for your reference

[People Picker doesn't show disabled accounts, what should i do to make people picker show disabled accounts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21536/people-picker-doesnt-show-disabled-accounts-what-should-i-do-to-make-people-pi)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you filtering them out in the UPS sync to begin with? (We do, so that's why I'm asking). Also, are they in a specific OU that your farm account is not seeing, or a specific OU that is not part of the UPS sync?